# Magic Square generator

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am attempting to develop a program that creates and prints an n X n "magic square" where n is an user generated odd integer. However, I keep getting the same error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3"

Summary of the algorithm:

1. Place 1 in the center of the first row ( row 0)
2. Place 2,3,4...n according to the following rules

Move up and right to a new position (row,col) i.e. row = row-1, col = col+1
if  row = -1 ( row is off the array), put the number in  the last/bottom row that is in (n-1, col)

if col = n (column is off the array), put the number in  (row, 0)

when moving from the top corner square, place the next number in the bottom left corner square if the place is taken, place the new number under the previous number

```
import java.util.*;
public class MagicSquare
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter an odd integer:");

int n = input.nextInt();

int[][] magic = new int[n][n];

int row = 0;
int col = (n-1)/2;
magic[row][col] = 1;

 for(int i=2; i <=n*n; i++)
{
   if(magic[row-1][col+1]==0){
     row=row-1;
     col=col+1;
   }
   else{
     row=row+1;
   }
   if(row==-1)
     row = n-1;
   if (col== n)
     col=0;
   magic[row][col]=i;
}
for(int x = 0; x<n; x++)
{
  for(int y=0; y<n; y++)
    System.out.print("|"+magic[x][y] +"|\t");
  System.out.println();
 }
}
}
```

Edit - Formatting

Comment: Can you reformat the rules please?  I'm having trouble parsing them - especially the bit at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, following your rules (thanks for reformatting them!):

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an odd integer:");

    int n = input.nextInt();

    int[][] magic = new int[n][n];

    // Place 1 in the center of the first row ( row 0)
    int row = 0;
    int col = (n-1)/2;
    magic[row][col] = 1;

    for(int i=2; i <=n*n; i++)
    {
       // Move up and right to a new position
       col = col + 1;
       row = row - 1;
       // row is off the array
       if (row == -1)
           row = n - 1;
       // col is off the array
       if (col == n)
           col = 0;
       // if the place is taken, place the new number under the previous number
       if( magic[row][col] !=0 )
       {
         row = row + 1;
         if (row == n)
           row = 0;
       }

       magic[row][col]=i;
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
      for(int y=0; y < n; y++)
        System.out.print("|"+magic[x][y] +"|\t");
      System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This is very similar to what you had with a change in the conditional (!= 0) to detect occupied places, and by separating out all of the additions and subtractions it becomes easier to see the combined result when several happen in a row.

I haven't tested this code, so it may still have problems but hopefully this will put you on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop you, you reset `row` to the end:

```
if(row==-1)
  row = n-1;
```

But then in the next iteration you index with `row + 1`:

```
if(magic[row+1][col+1]==0)
```

Which will be past the end.

Comment: Thank you, that was certainly part of the problem. I believe i have corrected it, I have put the updated loop in the question above. However, I am still experiencing an error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1." Any suggestions?